# How to avoid several failed attempts when re-indexing existing datastore data?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is an issue I hit a while ago when I was actively changing indexes. I had not needed to change my indexes for a long time but yesterday I had to make some changes. Once again, I spent several hours in the following loop:

```
1. Upload new index definitions
2. Indexing of some new complicated indexes fail after some time
3. Vacuum the failed indexes
4. when vacuum succeeds GoTo 1 if it fails Goto 3
```

I finally managed to get all of them working after several attempts. As step 4 suggests, even “removing an index" failed at times and had to be retried. I have some complicated indexes but not too much data in the big scheme of things.

I added 50 new indexes (the plan has been to remove 50 others later but since this is a 7x24 SaaS site the new and old indexes have to coexist for a while). The indexing of 42 indexes succeeded the first time. The other 8 caused the trouble I describe above. One characteristic of those indexes is that they index 2-3 order of magnitude more entities than the others. Here is an example of an index that failed many times before finally succeeding:

```
- kind: Audit
  ancestor: yes     # shallow hierarchy probably 3 levels max
  properties:
  - name: events      # List, 20 - 60 elements in a typical instance
  - name: effective_date   # datetime
    direction: desc
  - name: prop_date     # datetime
    direction: desc
  - name: __key__
    direction: desc
```

What has been your experience with re-indexing existing data? Is there any tip/workaround to avoid this?

Relevant issues I suggest you star:

[10419: Index Usage Statistics](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10419)

[6133: Improved index management](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6133)

Comment: Of course there is got to be an issue/real bug here, how can the same index with the same data fail three times to be indexed and succeed the fourth? Any insight on why re-indexing fails some times but no others?

Comment: Can you please show your index.yaml to help us gauge how close to the edge you're riding and why? It's quite possible to build an index so complex that it will time-out at least 3 times out of 4 but accidentally "get wind at its back" (particularly unloaded servers and networks) once in a blue moon and succeed.

Comment: @AlexMartelli I updated the description with one of the failing indexes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a lot of indexes, especially complex.

Every indexed property and every composite index increase data size and writing costs significantly. Instead, you may load more entities and then filter out unnecessary entities in code.

To illustrate, instead of indexing an address by country, state and city, you can index it by city only. Sure, there may be cities with the same name within a country or globally, but it's much cheaper to retrieve all records by `city` only, and then filter out one or two from the wrong country or state.

The same logic applies to any query where the expected number of results is relatively small.

NB: In 7 years of using the Datastore I have never seen an index build/removal fail.

Comment: Sorry I cannot consider this the answer. It is analogous to Q:"How do I keep my computer secure?" A: "Do not connect it to the internet, in the 7 years I owned a computer disconnected from the internet I never had a problem."

Comment: @gae123 so... what kind of answer you expect if this is a bug? Honestly, if you believe this is a bug, it doesn't hold much ground as a Stack Overflow question. I would suggest posting to our issue tracker and we'll be trying to root-cause and fix that cause. There's not much a community that doesn't know the back end of the system can do here...

Comment: @Patrice I am exploring all angles. There are several filed bugs for years that Google ignores, (e.g. #6311 filed in 2011). Even the GAE SDK has wording that says that when this happens retry. Maybe somebody has found a way to work around the pain of keep retrying.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you describe indicate you have an [exploding index](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Python_Index_limits).

The issue is not the number of entities in the kind, it is the number of index entries required. There is a limit of [20,000 index entries per entity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/#Python_Quotas_and_limits). There is a related limit of 2MB of encoded index entries. The most common cause of exceeding this limit is two index two repeated properties, since an index entry is required for each pair (cross product) of the properties.

Comment: if I am violating any limits why does it eventually succeed?

Comment: If the data stored is changing betweens attempts, you may have an entity that is near the limit and on some runs over and other runs under.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am not violating limits.

Comment: Do you see problems when removing an index?

If the application is writing to an entity group constantly (>= 1/sec) then its possible the writes will interfere with the indexing operation.

Comment: Yes, I did see the issue even when deleting a simple index. I am scared if this is the answer because then it means that the site has to go in maintenance mode while re-indexing... Have you seen this somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: You can reduce the chance of encountering this by (1) not writing to any entity group more than [1/sec](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Transactions_and_entity_groups) and (2) creating/deleting indexes 1 kind at a time (or multiple kinds that never share the same ancestors/entity groups). You should not need to stop all writes from the app, just remain under the 1/sec guideline.